# No keyboard on Nexus 7 installation

Tags: installation, ubuntu-touch, nexus-7

I installed Ubuntu on Nexus 7 but when i get prompted the installer on the tablet, i cant type anything. I also don't see the taskbar anywhere. is it a corrupt attempt to install on nexus 7?

Comment: What install guide did you use?  What steps were successful?

Comment: Try power-cycling (re-booting) at least once after install.